# JQuery UI Multiselect getting values from different multiselect blocks

Tags: jquery, multi-select

This is link to the root of my question:
[JQuery UI Multiselect how to get selected options values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749771/jquery-ui-multiselect-how-to-get-selected-options-values).
The problem was how to get `:selected` from the multiselect widget made by Michael Aufreiter.

There is also this solution to the problem:

```
$('.ui-multiselect .selected li').each(function(idx,el){
    var link = $(el).data('optionLink');
    if(link) {
        selFriends.push(link.val()); //array with selected items
    }
});
```

But I'm going to add a second multiselect block with the same data. This means that   `$('.ui-multiselect .selected li')` will get `:selected` elements from both widgets. That's wrong and I don't know how to modify code above. For example, I have two select blocks with different IDs, how can I make jQuery recognize from where is the element?

---

As final target: I need to push selected elements from first widget to `selFriends` array and selected elements from the second to `anotherArray`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more simple way to get selected values, if you are using [that multiselect widget](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/)

In example, if you have element `<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries[]">...</select>` (like the example in link), you can get selected values like this:

```
var selectedValuesArray = $('#countries').val(); // ["AUT", "DEU"]

// second multiselect with id #anotherSelect
var anotherValuesArray = $('#anotherSelect').val();
```